# Google amp html - как динамически загрузить скрипты и amp-html по кнопке

Tags: html, amp

Есть amp форма открывающаяся в lightbox, при нажатии кнопки в меню. Присутствует на всех страницах но редко используется. Возможно ли динамически загрузить amp скрипты и html динамически, при нажатии на кнопку? Есть и другие кандидаты на динамическую загрузку, цель - ускорить сайт.

В заголовке скрипта вот это хотелось бы грузить только по необходимости:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
```

Вот код формы:

```
<amp-lightbox
  id=checkin-lightbox
  layout="nodisplay"
  class="popup-lightbox">
...
<form method="post"
    action-xhr="checkin_xhr.php"
    target="_top"
    on="submit-success:checkin-lightbox.close,checkin-lightbox-message">
...
```

Comment: Получилось найти решение? Если да, то могли бы вы показать решение.